# Vertices of a complete graph $K_6$ are painted in black and white: find a subgraph $K_3$ with vertices of the same color

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Vertices of a complete graph $K_6$ are painted in black and white. Show that it contains a subgraph $K_3 \subset K_6$ with vertices of same color.

I am quite newbie at discrete maths. So, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a special case of the finite Ramsey theorem; you’ll find a proof of this particular case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Example:_R.283.2C3.29_.3D_6). Read it first, and if you still have questions, you can make your question more specific.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I understand now.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: The standard Ramsey example is about edge coloring. This is about vertex coloring and much simpler: there must be at least 3 black vertices or at least 3 white vertices. Any three vertices in a complete graph combine to a $K_3$.

Answer (score 1):

> there must be at least 3 black vertices or at least 3 white vertices. Any three vertices in a complete graph combine to a $K_3$. -- [Leen Droogendijk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584803/vertices-of-a-complete-graph-are-painted-in-black-and-white#comment1236336_584803)

Note that the above remains true if $K_6$ is replaced with $K_5$.